# I2C OLED does not display properly

Tags: arduino, i2c, oled

I am using a 1.3' 128x64 OLED display bought from a site I don't remember(probably no-name), using the SSD1306 drivers, with an Arduino Nano. I have connected the SDA->A4, SCL->A5, as indicated by the datasheet, then booted up an Adafruit sketch included with the SSD1306 library.

After changing the I2C address to the corresponding one, I notice that only rows 2-8 inclusively are being changed/used. I have tried using the U8Glib library, as was advised on another post in this community, but to no avail, and now i have the incomplete "hello world" message(in Chinese as well) stuck on the display instead of the semi-blank white screen.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrSmt.jpg) is what it looks like now when trying to run the Adafruit sketch a second time. Any help is appreciated, as I cannot seem to find anything about this online. It does not seem to be broken, as the screen was mostly white at first run of Adafruit code, but after uploading U8Glib code, it was all black with the white text, alas still not aligned properly.

Edit: I am sorry for weird angle of filming, but the behavior can be seen either way

Comment: I have recently bought one of the 1.3'' OLED, and no success using SSD1306. Most of the lines were scrambled when i have tried to use my OLED with this software driver. After some tinkering I found this display to be a different driver (not SSD1306) namely: SH1106. How I found it? Using example from u8glib, try to uncomment some I2C and resolution specified drivers. Mine was 128x64, thus reducing possibilities a lot. Don't uncomment all, do it one-by-one, until you see desired output (I know, it takes some time).

Comment: @smajli thanks, that seems to be indeed the case. Also, what library do you recommend to use in the case of an SH1106 128x64 display? I am unsure where to start. Also the ability of creating an animation would be something i'd like, if you have any ideas.

Comment: I have used u8glib (There is a newer one, but I have used this one with success) Install it from Arduino IDE. I can make this an answer with some pictures... I am not sure if this library is fast enough to do the animations.

Comment: @smajli I have installed both U8glib and U82, but to me they seem rather complicated... Ended up using OneBitDisplay library but in a sad turn of events I think I bricked my board when trying to use sprintf() function...